# Wordpress select for multiple meta_keys?

Tags: wordpress

I can do this.

```
mysql> select * from wp_postmeta where post_id = '1304090';
+---------+---------+-------------------+--------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
+---------+---------+-------------------+--------------+
| 4965987 | 1304090 | mp_tax_inclusive | 3 |
| 4965988 | 1304090 | mp_tax_shipping | 5 |
| 4965989 | 1304090 | mp_order_items | 1 |
| 4965985 | 1304090 | mp_shipping_tax | 0 |
+---------+---------+-------------------+--------------+
```

I now want to find all post_id's where meta_key "mp_tax_shipping" = 5 AND meta_key "mp_tax_inclusive" = 3. How can I specify both? I can specify one with:

`select * from wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'mp_tax_shipping' and meta_value = '5'`

but I need both criteria met. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  pm.post_id
FROM
  wp_postmeta AS pm
INNER JOIN
  wp_postmeta AS pm2 ON pm2.post_id = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = 'mp_tax_shipping' AND pm.meta_value = '5' AND
  pm2.meta_key = 'mp_tax_inclusive' AND pm2.meta_value = '3'
```